# What kind of .cs extention file include both design and code? C#

Tags: c#, forms

I have 2 question.

1.When I create new form with Visual studio then Form design and code are separate files.

Form1.cs
Form1.Designer.cs
Form1.resx
But I downloaded `"sample_client.cs"` from internet which has both design and code in same   `"sample_client.cs"` file.Why is that? Was it made by Visual Studio or not?

1. Why some Windows form source is XAML?

Is there something special about it?

Comment: If you're looking at some very old code that's not been updated from the .NET 1.1/VS2003 days then you'll find all of the code in a single file.

Answer (score 2):

One question a time:

1. `Form1.cs` and `Form1.Designer.cs` contain the same class as [Partial Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/wa80x488.aspx). The second is updated by the IDE itself, the first one by the developer. The example you downloaded probably comes from an other development environments. To discover which is, you have to open the project file and dig into it...
2. The XAML files belong to the [Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms754130%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) technology, the example you provided with ".cs .resx" file belongs to [Windows Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd30h2yb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) technology.

Answer (score 1):

There is a language feature in C# that allows classes to be split into multiple files by using the "partial" keyword.

This is mostly used for splitting a class in an auto-generated part and a user defined part. It can be a good thing to separate user code from the auto-generated to avoid custom code to get overwritten by the generator. This is why the Visual Studio designer splits the same Forms class in a .designer.cs part and a .cs part.

The .designer.cs file is really just plain code for initializing the Form and since it is the same class it can be merged into one file, which is probably what someone has done here.

Comment: Thanks. At least I learned something. How can I specify which mode I want to use when I start new form?

Comment: By default Visual Studio will split the form class in two. The .designer.cs file will be auto-updated when ever you change something in the graphical GUI designer (e.g. adds a new control, change some caption, etc.). In the non- .designer class you can have your event handlers and the likes in peace. Sometimes you want to create a custom control so customized that you don't want the autogenerated initialization at all. In that case it makes sense to merge the two and simply delete the .designer file.